# Getting error in Visual code studio "ImportError: cannot import name 'DummyOperator' from 'airflow.operators'

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

Getting error while running the airflow DAG code in visual studio code.

**Error**

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DummyOperator' from 'airflow.operators' (c:\Users\10679196\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\airflow\operators\__init__.py)
```

**Import Statement**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import DummyOperator
```

**Version**

```
apache-airflow : 2.4.2
python : 3.8.1
pip : 22.3
```

Comment: try to install the apache-airflow module - `pip install apache-airflow` or add it to your requirements file

Comment: Already tried to install apache-airflow module but it shows requirement already satisfied

Comment: What version of AF are u using?

Comment: Sorry for late reply but issue was testing in local env . Working fine when tested in airflow DAG

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.4/_api/airflow/operators/dummy/index.html) the DummyOperator is deprecated and beginning with the version 2.4.0 is not supported any more.
You should use

```
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
```

BTW your old import seems also incorrect. For airflow < 2.4.0 this should work:

```
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
```